# Printing the Pair of Numbers in desired format

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stl-algorithm

Given pair of numbers,where frequency of each number is even(sum of frequency of both columns)

```
1 4
1 5
2 3
3 4
2 5
```

how could i modify the arrangement to a form such that each column has equal frequency count which would be half of the total frequency of a number in both column,i am only allowed to swap two column entries.

```
1 4
5 1
3 2
4 3
2 5
```

Can someone give me a hint,also make sure all components are connected in graph representation ,if disconnected print -1?

EDIT: the numbers are in n rows and two columns.

```
row1/col1:1
row1/col2:4
row2/col1:1
row2/col2:5
```

and the rest

Comment: i am using cpp,i have tried to count the number of appearances of each number in two colums in two separate array..and tried to make the values equal but conflict arises for the cases like above with this approach

Comment: Problem seems unclear. Could you reformulate it? What does given example mean?

Comment: @MBo the frequency of each number is 2 in this case(like 1 in col1 and another 1 in col2) this frequency might be different for every number.i need to readjust the two columns such that the both columns have equal division of frequency.ie each number should appear 2/2=1 inleft and right column,i am only allowed to swap the two columns,a<->b.

Comment: this is not a printing issue,its an algorithmic task,if u still did not get what i need to explain,i could elaborate more?

Comment: It is needed to change title and edit question with this information, it is more clear. Is count for every value always 2?

Comment: @MBo no,it is not always 2..take this case for example:
1 2
2 3
3 4
2 4
2 5
1 5
required:
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 2
2 5
5 1

Comment: So describe how to deal with count=3 and so on.

Comment: there will always be even count

Comment: Edit the question. Take care about question quality. People are not telepathic.

Comment: @MBo yeah i will,edit it.thanks

Comment: @MBo how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

That very interesting puzzle!

First what we need to do is to describe the problem in the graph theory. Vertices in the graph are numbers from the array. In your particular example it will be {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. For every row we have edge, so in the example we get such graph:

[image]

This is undirected graph. Out goal is to direct every edge. If we have edge *u, v* we can direct it in one of two ways:

- *u -> v*, that means that we chose row to be: *u v*
- *v -> u*, that means that we chose row to be: *v u*

For every vertex *u* number of outgoing edges corresponds to number of frequency count of *u* in the left column. In the same way ingoing edges corresponds to number of frequency count in the right column.

Please notice, that if find direction of edges which satisfied condition: every vertex has the same number of ingoing and outgoing edges, we will also find the solution for original problem.

So now let me describe how to find these directions.

We will use two thesis:

1. Undirected graph has Eulerian circuit if and only if for every vertex *u*, number of its edges is even.
2. Directed graph has Eulerian circuit if and only if for every vertex *u*, *u* has the same number of ingoing and outgoing edges.

Just for case if you have never heard about Eulerian circuits :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path

From 1. we know, that the graph always has solution (because, as you wrote at the beginning *frequency of each number is even*). From 2. we get the algorithm to find solution: first we have to find the Eulerian circuit, and then direct every edge according to its appearance in the circuit.

And there is the good tutorial how to find Eulerian circuit:

[Looking for algorithm finding euler path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467228/looking-for-algorithm-finding-euler-path)

Comment: i know i could find a euler path using fleury's algorithm but i am looking for a solution which is rather analytical and deals with frequencies without getting into graph traversal.Thanks for help though!

Comment: assuming the graph is undirected and traversing it and noting the path and then making amends to print the result in front of corresponding edge would take lot of time.theres has to be a faster solution by brute force

Comment: @user6944972 The proposed algorithm walks over each edge (line in the original input) just once, making it O(n). It's hard to imagine being faster than that; certainly you won't get faster with brute force.

Comment: This is a beautiful observation. Just one really minor side comment: it may be worth mentioning that this has to be done separately for each connected component.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

First, just summarizing the problem:

We have two columns with a number of different tokens in them.
Each token appears an even number of times. The goal is to swap rows such that in the end, each token appears an equal number of times in each column.

First I go through all the data, counting how many times each token appears.

Then for each token, I iterate through each column and check if that particular token appears. If I encounter more than n/2 tokens in that column, then it gets swapped.

This whole procedure is repeated until no more swapping was necessary.

I'm unsure of two things: a) will there, in general, always be a solution to the problem (I'm almost sure that this must be the case...)? B) Can I be sure that the iteration will always stop. I.e. it will not get stuck swapping things back and forth?

Anyway, here is some code that does this. Please note that there is no checking if the input is correct etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class my_pair
{
    private:
        int m_x,m_y;

    public:
        my_pair( int x, int y ) : m_x( x ), m_y( y ) {}

        void swap()
        {
            int tmp = m_x;
            m_x = m_y;
            m_y = tmp;
        }

        int x()
        {
            return m_x;
        }
        int y()
        {
            return m_y;
        }
};

int main()
{
    // Generate some input:
    // I'm assuming that the tokens in the columns are
    // in the form 0,1,2 etc such that the tokens
    // themselves can be interpreted as an index of an array.
    // I think there is no loss of generality here, as it can
    // be considered a re-labeling...

    vector<my_pair> pair_vector;

    pair_vector.push_back( my_pair( 0,1 ) );
    pair_vector.push_back( my_pair( 1,1 ) );
    pair_vector.push_back( my_pair( 2,2 ) );
    pair_vector.push_back( my_pair( 2,1 ) );
    pair_vector.push_back( my_pair( 2,0 ) );
    pair_vector.push_back( my_pair( 2,1 ) );
    pair_vector.push_back( my_pair( 2,1 ) );
    pair_vector.push_back( my_pair( 2,2 ) );

    cout << "Start vector:" << endl;

    for( auto p : pair_vector )
        cout << p.x() << ' ' << p.y() << endl;

    // 1: Count number of occurrences of each token.
    // Here the assumption on the tokens is used:
    vector<int> num_tokens;

    for( auto& p : pair_vector )
    {
        if( p.x()+1 > num_tokens.size() )
            num_tokens.resize( p.x()+1 );

        num_tokens[p.x()]++;

        if( p.y()+1 > num_tokens.size() )
            num_tokens.resize( p.y()+1 );

        num_tokens[p.y()]++;
    }


    // 2. Now I iterate through the columns for each token
    // and swap each token
    // that appears more often than n/2 times in that column,
    // where n is the number of appearances of each token:
    bool swap_was_performed = true;

    while( swap_was_performed )
    {
        int token = 0;
        swap_was_performed = false;

        for( auto& n : num_tokens ) // n is the number (or frequency) of tokens
        {
            int x_ctr = 0;
            int y_ctr = 0;

            // Iterating through the input columns:
            for( auto& p : pair_vector )
            {
                if( p.x()==token ) // x-values (i.e. the first column)
                {
                    x_ctr++;

                    if( x_ctr>n/2 )
                    {
                        p.swap();
                        swap_was_performed = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            for( auto& p : pair_vector )
            {
                if( p.y()==token ) // y-values...
                {
                    y_ctr++;

                    if( y_ctr>n/2 )
                    {
                        p.swap();
                        swap_was_performed = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            token++;
        }
    }


    cout << "After re-arranging:" << endl;

    for( auto p : pair_vector )
        cout << p.x() << ' ' << p.y() << endl;

}
```

Comment: It is not necessary that there will always be a solution but i have figured out the failing cases.This algorithm is a bit dubious.i also had a solution like this but this fails in many cases.

Comment: yeah the iteration will stop when every element is in its required state.

Comment: In some cases the iteration will not stop and enter a state where it swaps entries in rows back and forth. The reason is that it goes through the column from top to bottom and starts swapping everything in its way after N/2 of an entry has been reached. The key is to know which of the candidates to swap. One immediate improvement would be a Monte Carlo approach, i.e. randomly select the candidates to swap and iterate until you find a solution. I'm not sure that even this will be enough to guarantee a solution...

Comment: i came up with a soultion but the complexity of it is exponential which is not good.